# How to reduce spacing between items xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have a StackLayout and a label, the spacing between the two is very large, I want to decrease so that the two are as close together as possible, in what way I do this

```
       <ScrollView BackgroundColor="#ffffff" Padding="15">
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="200"  x:Name="image">
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
            <Button x:Name="Amais" Text="A+" />
            <Button x:Name="Amenos" Text="A-" />
       </StackLayout>

        <Label x:Name="webView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="18"/>
    </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: Lets try this again, set `Spacing` to `0` on the parent `StackLayout` and removed the `VerticalOptions` on the `Label` and on the parent `StackLayout`. Does that get you the results your after?

```
 <ScrollView BackgroundColor="#ffffff" Padding="15">
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Spacing="0">
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="200"  x:Name="image">
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="Amais" Text="A+" />
            <Button x:Name="Amenos" Text="A-" />
       </StackLayout>

        <Label x:Name="webView" FontSize="18"/>
    </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, same divergence

Comment: Look at the photo above